AEM/sightly : How to remove /n/n on text injection
Code example:
"description": "${model.description @ context='scriptString'}"
Or something else that I am trying to do is getting just the last paragraph.
Expected Output:
Paragraph 1. Paragraph 2. Paragraph 3.
Current Situation:
Paragraph 1.
Paragraph 2.
Paragraph 4.

Is your description field is a richtext? and in the source in crxde do you see \n or you see paragraphs wrapped in  tag?

HTL/Sightly syntax is not designed to support this kind of string manipulation, you should do it in your model object.

Another option is to create a component filter. The question is to varuge to give an adaquate answer.
